# Workspace switcher for 18,04 , desktop and laptop?

Tags: gnome-shell

Where is the **workspace switcher** for the desktop, 18.04; and the same  question for a new 18.04 laptop?

Comment: https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-workspaces-switch.html.en?

Answer (score 2):

Open the **GNOME Tweaks** application and enable the Top Bar/Activities Overview Hot Corner...

[image]

Then close **GNOME Tweaks**, and from now on, you can move your mouse pointer to the upper-left corner of your screen. The workspaces will appear on the right side of the screen. Click on any workspace to switch to it.

Comment: "Move your mouse pointer to the upper-left corner of your screen" *and click*! Hot corner is disabled by default in a standard fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04 (i.e. without vanilla GNOME).

Comment: @pomsky Answer modified. 18.04 upgrades must behave differently then. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @heynnema, perhaps you upgraded from an Ubuntu Gnome, which would explain that for you the hotcorner was enabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

Above your launch locker you will see Activities, if you click there you can see on your right two space works, if you click on the second you switch to a new one, you can repeat the process and open several working spaces.

Hope it helps.